# Print a kstream content without increasing offset

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am currently performing my first steps on kafka streams and I have difficulties understanding how kafka application stores its state.
I would like to print the content of a kstream without having the offset updated, it feels like this is not something that I should want to do but I am struggling to understand why:

```
  def rawPlanningStream(
      builder: StreamsBuilder,
      topicName: String
  ): KStream[String, Planning] =
    builder.stream(topicName)(Consumed.`with`(Serdes.String, Planning.serde))

  def printPlanning(
    key: String,
    value: Planning
  ) = {
    val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("PlanningEventSyncLogger")
    logger.warn(s"Planning: $key, $value")
  }


def process(
      builder: StreamsBuilder,
      rawTopic: String
    ) = {
    val raw_planning_stream = PlanningEventSync.rawPlanningStream(
      builder,
      rawTopic
    )

    raw_planning_stream.peek((k,v) => printPlanning(k,v))

    //Here I would like to perform an operation on raw_planning_stream
    //but offset is already "wrong" because of the peek done earlier

   }
```

The first time I start process the content of the topic is printed as intended, if I start it again it no longer prints anything as the offset was updated.

My question is is it possible to perform 'non invasive' operations like a print in order to leave the offset as it is?

(note: I managed to use --reset-offsets --to-earliest from kafka-consumer-groups.sh on my group in order to manually reset the offset, but I would like to be able to programmatically perform operations without changing the offset for my consumer group)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot set `enable.auto.commit=false`, then the other option is to set `application.id="<some random UUID>"` so that every time you run the app, it'll create a new consumer group, starting from `auto.offset.reset` setting

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I confirm that if I restart my app with a different ```application.id``` it reads from a reset offset and prints my stream. My problem is I would like during the same run to print witthout modifying the offset then perform some operations.
Also I set the ```enable.auto.commit=false```  but I do not see any change (the offset is still updated after I print)

Comment: Also it looks like I was already with the default config ```enable.auto.commit=false``` because when I try to put the ConsumerConfig:

```ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG -> false```

It says:

``` Unexpected user-specified consumer config: enable.auto.commit found. User setting (false) will be ignored and the Streams default setting (false) will be used```

Comment: If you want to perform an action and print, then just print within a `map()` function

Comment: I think what I did not understand is it is not possible to map/peek/foreach on a stream without incrementing the offset. So what I initially wanted to do, print first using one of these functions then do another map/peek/foreach on the same stream to perform something else is not the correct way to go.

Comment: AFAIK, `peek` is a pass-through operation. It can go before or after other non-terminal action just fine, so `raw_planning_stream.peek((k,v) => printPlanning(k,v)).map((k,v) => ...)` should have worked. But the offsets do need reset if you are making any topology changes